# How to model a dependency graph in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am stuck modelling the following relationship in a new application:
A **Module** can require (many) other **Modules**.

In Laravel I added the Module model and a ModuleRequirement model with its migrations. The second one has a foreign id field for the module it belongs to:

```
Schema::create('module_requirements', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('module_id')->constrained();

    // How to reference other modules?
    $table->integer('requires');
});
```

The relationship itself is defined by:

```
// Module.php

public function moduleRequirements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ModuleRequirement::class);
}
```

This method returns a collection of ModuleRequirements as expected. Unfortunately in order to get the real Module objects I need a foreach loop and build my own collection. I wonder if there is a simpler and faster solution. The perfect way I could imagine is sth. like $module->moduleRequirements returning a collection of the actual models instead of its ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding that a module has relation with other modules in the same table.
you should use many to many relationship ,in that case you will not need a model for `ModuleRequirement` just a pivot table would be sufficient.

In your case `module_requirements`  would act as the pivot table and you just need to change the relation in `Module.php` to :-

```
 public function moduleRequirements(){
        return $this->belongsTomany(Module::class,"module_requirements", 'module_id', 'requires');
    }
```

the migration should be something  like :-

```
Schema::create('module_requirements', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->foreignId('module_id');
 $table->foreignId('requires');
 $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('models')->onDelete('cascade');
 $table->foreign('requires')->references('id')->on('models')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Woah! That worked perfectly fine, thank you so much for the quick help, Mohammed!